# How to I convert custom function in JPA to a Predicate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I've got a custom implementation of function (interface `SQLFunction`) that looks as follows:

```
public class FilterFunction implements SQLFunction {

    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return StandardBasicTypes.STRING;
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List arguments, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        return arguments.get(0).toString();
    }
}
```

So it simply takes a parameter and replaces the function with it. The SQL might look like this:

```
HUGE_SQL = 'SOME_VALUE' AND HUGE_SQL2 = 'SOME_VALUE'
```

So it is some kind of predicate. I'm using the function in the following way:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class);
criteriaBuilder.function("filter", String.class, parameterExpression));
```

I would like to use disjunction with several such functions passing an array of them to `CriteriaBuilder.or`. The function is an `Expression` implementation. But `CriteriaBuilder.or` takes an array of `Predicate`'s. I've tried to convert such function to a `Predicate` but I'm getting cast exception on runtime.

I've tried to wrap this function in `CriteriaBuilder.isTrue`. Then I have to specify the return type of the function `Boolean.class` instead of `String.class` but then I'm getting another runtime exception saying it can't convert my function to boolean.

I have to do it because I have to use JPA Criteria API.

How do I chain such functions in `CriteriaBuilder.or`? Thank you very much!